# How to correctly parse a VB Case statement?

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm trying to parse VBA code, and the 5.4.2.10 section of the spec defines the `Select Case` statement, which we've defined as follows:

```
// 5.4.2.10 Select Case Statement
selectCaseStmt :
    SELECT whiteSpace? CASE whiteSpace? selectExpression endOfStatement
    caseClause*
    caseElseClause?
    END_SELECT
;
selectExpression : expression;
caseClause :
    CASE whiteSpace rangeClause (whiteSpace? COMMA whiteSpace? rangeClause)* endOfStatement block
;
caseElseClause : CASE whiteSpace? ELSE endOfStatement block;
rangeClause :
    expression
    | selectStartValue whiteSpace TO whiteSpace selectEndValue   
    | (IS whiteSpace?)? comparisonOperator whiteSpace? expression
;
selectStartValue : expression;
selectEndValue : expression;
```

The problem is that the `expression` in `rangeClause` is taking precedence, and makes this:

> ```
> Select Case foo
>     Case Is = 42
>         Exit Sub
> End Select
> ```

...ultimately get picked up and treated as `{undeclared-variable} {EQ} {literal}`, which is a problem, because `Is` ought to be a lexer token, not the LHS of a comparison expression:

```
expression whiteSpace? (EQ | NEQ | LT | GT | LEQ | GEQ | LIKE | IS) whiteSpace? expression    # relationalOp
```

I tried reordering the alternatives so that the `expression` branch has lower precedence, like this:

```
rangeClause :
    selectStartValue whiteSpace TO whiteSpace selectEndValue   
    | (IS whiteSpace?)? comparisonOperator whiteSpace? expression
    | expression
;
```

But that broke the entire grammar in all kinds of ways (breaks ~1000 tests in my project), so instead I tried changing the `rangeClause` to this (removed optional tokens, because `Is` without `=` is actually illegal VBA code):

```
rangeClause :
      expression (whiteSpace TO whiteSpace expression)?                 #caseFromTo
    | (IS whiteSpace comparisonOperator whiteSpace)? expression         #caseIs
;
```

And then working with `CaseFromToContext` and `CaseIsContext` classes in the code (had to, to keep it compiling), but again it broke ~1000 tests in my project.

Then I figured, "hey that's potentially ambiguous!" and turned it into this:

```
rangeClause :
      expression whiteSpace TO whiteSpace expression                    #caseFromTo
    | IS whiteSpace comparisonOperator whiteSpace expression            #caseIs
    | expression                                                        #caseExpr
;
```

...but no luck, same identical outcome.

How can I make the `rangeClause` understand this annoying `Case Is = foobar` syntax? I'm using ANTLR 4.3, but we're planning to upgrade to ANTLR 4.6 soon-ish.

If additional context is needed, [the complete VBAParser.g4 grammar is on github](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/next/Rubberduck.Parsing/Grammar/VBAParser.g4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that re-ordering actually does work, but in order to keep the ambiguity out of the parse, the `IS whiteSpace comparisonOperator` has to come first:

```
rangeClause :
    (IS whiteSpace?)? comparisonOperator whiteSpace? expression
    | selectStartValue whiteSpace TO whiteSpace selectEndValue 
    | expression
```

The problem is with `expression` (and by extension `selectStartValue` and `selectEndValue`) which will recursively match `Is =` because `comparisonOperator comparisonOperator` is an expression match.  There's probably some work that can be done to *prevent* `comparisonOperator comparisonOperator` from matching `expression` (it's never valid in VBA AFAIK), but the above works as a quick and dirty fix.

Basically all the above grammar does is ensure that the "invalid" `comparisonOperator comparisonOperator` matches as a `rangeClause` *before* it can be matched as an `expression`.